# how to make two mapper functions run parallel?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I read this python documentation on [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

But I had a requirement like following:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def f(x):
    print(x)
    time.sleep(100000000000000);
    return x*x

def f2(x):
    print('**' + str(x) + '**')
    time.sleep(100000000000000);
    return x*x*x;
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
    print(p.map(f2,[1,2,3]))
```

I have a use case where the function f is blocking(in my case it listens to a rabbitmq queue, so it should be blocking. I used a long time delay-100000000000000 to imply the infinite time blocking). 
I have simulated blocking with the time.delay here.

but the need is i want the f2 (which is different from f) to start and run parallel. At present it does not even go to f2 as f itself blocks.

Can someone please give some guidance on how to make f and f2 start parallely despite the fact being f and f2 are both blocking.

**Update:**

Seems like i found a way, but puzzled

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def f(x):
    print(x)
    time.sleep(100000000000000);
    return x*x

def f2(x):
    print('**' + str(x) + '**')
    time.sleep(100000000000000);
    return x*x*x;

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    res = p.apply_async(f, [2])
    res = p.apply_async(f2,[4])
    res.get()
```

how even after reassigning res1 it works and it invokes even f ?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach doesn't work since first pool must complete to be able to print the result *before* the second pool. So the `print` kind of blocks the second pool from starting.

I used a thread pool to start both wrappers simultaneously, and I get the results asynchronously. I had to make a loop instead of the big `sleep` because python complained that sleep was too large. But amounts to the same thing.
In my case, there are printouts of 1,2,3 **1**,**2**,**3** at once. And if I set the wait loop to a reasonable value I even get some correct results.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import concurrent.futures


import time

sleep_times = 1000000

def f(x):
    print(x)
    for i in range(sleep_times):
        time.sleep(10)
    return x*x

def f2(x):
    print('**' + str(x) + '**')
    for i in range(sleep_times):
        time.sleep(10)
    return x*x*x;

def fwrap(l):
    p = Pool(len(l))
    return(p.map(f, l))

def fwrap2(l):
    p = Pool(len(l))
    return(p.map(f2, l))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jr = dict()
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        jr[executor.submit(fwrap, (1, 2, 3))] = "f"
        jr[executor.submit(fwrap2, (1, 2, 3))] = "f2"

    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(jr):
        ident = jr[future]
        print(ident,future.result())
```

output (when sleep loop reduced to 1 to avoid waiting for too long)

```
1
**1**
2
**2**
**3**
3
```

there it waits a while (blocked by "processing time") then:

```
('f', [1, 4, 9])
('f2', [1, 8, 27])
```

Comment: hi, my code under apply_async seems to work .. i don't know how. can u guide ?

Comment: `apply_async` only works for 1 value. You seem to want to build a list using a list as input. `apply_async` won't do that. You'll have to rebuild the order of the results from the order of the inputs.

Comment: no i wanted both f and f2 to start and one should not block the other, that is happening right ?

Comment: yes, but I thought you wanted to pass a list and retrieve a list.

Comment: no ,, i wanted the two blocking functions f and f2 to start simultaneously

Comment: then you found your answer. But your question says otherwise. Well, you're using `res` for both results so you'll lose one with your current code.

Comment: that is what confuses me .. it is working .. it invokes f2 and f .. can u try executing it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125457/discussion-between-harish-kayarohanam-and-jean-francois-fabre).